# Time series index data update certain consecutive rows for all the columns

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, datetimeindex

**Date-index**    **A B C D E F**

:::::::

**2019-06-01**    *3 4 5 9 2 4*

**2019-07-01**    *8 0 4 5 2 3*

**2019-08-01**    *1 8 9 7 5 6*

**2019-09-01**    *2 5 0 7 6 3*

::::

Update values to all the column for the slice of data for the date index ** '2019-06-01' : '2019-09-01'**

Is there any way to update the slice of data frame with new values?

Comment: Do you want to update how exactly?

Comment: Did you try `df.loc['2019-06-01' : '2019-09-01'] = something_new_here`?